# Yii Query Builder: Parametr binding using where() method

Tags: yii2

I have this code in my controller:

```
class ArchController extends Controller
{
public function actionIndex(string $date, array $rubric_id )
{
   $articles = Article::find()->where('published < :date', [':date' => $date])
                               ->andWhere(['in', 'rubric', $rubric_id])
                               ->andWhere('ISNULL(arch)')->all(); 
...
```

It seems to me it is not safe because $rubric_id is user input. How can I make parametr binding, something like this:

```
':rubric_id' => $rubric_id
```

Comment: how come the input `$rubric_id` is an `array` ? is it like some multi-select dropdown that you are submitting with mulitple id's as an array ?

Comment: Yes, it's multi-select dropdown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yii uses parameter binding internally, so it is safe to use `->andWhere(['in', 'rubric', $rubric_id])`. You can review implementation of [`InConditionBuilder`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-conditions-inconditionbuilder) to make sure of that.